# How to find the intensity Gradient in Canny Edge detector

Tags: c, opencv

I am implementing the cvCanny in OpenCV. after using cvCanny to an image, i want to find the intensity gradient of the edges so that i can reject weaker edges by applying the threshold. how can i find the intensity gradient?

Comment: if you intend to eliminate weaker edges only, then the parameters of cvCanny() should help - the larger parameter decided how long an edge-line should be before it is considered to be a strong edge, the smaller parameter decided how close edges should be before they are linked.

Comment: using your threshold concept you might consider taking the first derivative using Sobel then thresholding, though the results may not be that good - most sobel edges appear faint anyways. After that some Morphology closing might make them properly visible. HTH.

Comment: i am trying to select a subimage in an image and use canny to find that. but when i move my mouse to select that area, many unwanted images are also selected. so i want to use incremental canny edge detection, to remove that unwanted edges. but i dont know how... :) any algorithm for that?

Comment: in the incremental canny edge detection, with every new mouse position, the system will calculate the strong edges and reject the weaker, unwanted edges...

Comment: from what i gather you might consider this - just run the Canny on selected subimage with stricter parameters. the mouse handling you may have to code yourself.

Comment: i used canny with stricter parameters, but still the unwanted edges are present. if i make it more tough, the edges that i want will be gone.. so i must find an iterative way to reject the unwanted edges...

Comment: alright, have you tried using Morphology? Maybe a Closing operation with an experimentally determined kernel size might eliminate your unwanted edges. Could you post a sample image as that could make things clearer?

Answer (score 0):

For each white pixel of the Canny image check the corresponding gradient intensity in the Sobel edge images (the gradient magnitude = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)).

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand. check pixel of canny image in sobel edge image? means? i do canny as well as sobel and then get the gradient intensity from sobel? also, for pixel (x,y) what is dx and dy?

Comment: Yes. You perform cvSobel twice, once for each direction, and you get the vertical image derivative image (dx) and the horizontalimage derivative image (dy). Canny does this internally as well.

Comment: @Adi Shavit ,  i got it. let me do this and then i will let you know about the result...

Comment: this process (perform cvSobel twice) i have to do at every new mouse position. right? then i can use a threshold to reject the weaker edges?

Comment: I didn't understand the mouse reference. You run Canny and Sobel once per (whole) image. What and how you display is another matter.

Comment: i am trying to select a portion of the image (selected by cursor movement)and then do the painterly rendering in that selected portion. for this i need to find the edge of that selected portion (e.g., only the face in a portrait). to find the edges i used the cvCanny. but when the user roughly moves the cursor, many unwanted edges of the surrounding are also getting selected. but i need to reject those unwanted edges and get only the desired edge. i thought to use the intensity gradient and find it at every cursor position. then i can reject the weaker, unwanted edges using a threshold.

Comment: what say you?? any other way?